# How to run this differential eq MATLAB program

Tags: matlab

Please kindly help I'm new at MATLAB. My lecturer give me MATLAB code for diff eq. question and it can show animation of pendulum and graph. but i dont know how to use his code, I know how to run it but dont know where can I input my diff eq. the code i copy has its own diff eq. but i dont know which one and also it doesnt have any comment so i would know how to use it. This is the code, maybe someone can teach me how to use it or maybe make the code more easy to read

```
clc 
close all 
clear all

a=1;b=-2;c=2;b=b/a;c=c/a;
dt=.001;tap=1;btsa=tap;btsb=-tap; 
y0=0;y1=1;
y1=y0-y1*dt;
n=40;
for k=1:n;
    px(k)=(-1)^k*.1;
end
px=[0 0 px 0 0];
g0=0;
g=0;
for k=1:4000;

    t=k*dt;
    g=exp(-t);
    g=g/a;
    y=((2+b*dt-c*dt^2)*y0+g*dt^2-y1)/(1+b*dt);
    by=y+.3;
    py=linspace(by,tap-.3,n+1)-(tap-.3-by)/(2*n);
    py(1)=py(1)+(tap-.3-by)/(2*n);
    py=[y py tap-.3 tap];
    subplot(2,2,1)
    hold off
    plot([-2 2],[tap tap],'Color','k','LineWidth',4)
    hold on
    plot([0 4],[y y],'Color',[.8 .8 .8]);
    plot(px,py,'-r')
    plot(0,y,'--o','MarkerFaceColor',[1 0 0],'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0 0],'MarkerSize',20)
    axis([-3 3 -tap+.1 tap+.1])
    subplot(2,2,2)
    plot([0 k*dt+10],[0 0],'-k')
    hold on
    gam=plot([0 (k+1)*dt],[y y],'Color',[.8 .8 .8]);
    plot([k*dt (k+1)*dt],[y0 y],'-b')
    btsa=max(max(btsa,g),y);btsb=min(min(btsb,g),y);
    axis([0 max(10,k*dt)+.5 btsb-.1 btsa+.1])
    
    y1=y0;y0=y;
    subplot(2,2,4)
    plot([0 k*dt+10],[0 0],'-k')
    hold on
    plot([k*dt (k+1)*dt],[g0 g],'-r')
    axis([0 max(10,k*dt)+.5 btsb-.1 btsa+.1])
    g0=g;
    pause(.1)
    delete(gam)
end
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try running the code line by line in the debugger, and see the effect of each line. It will help you understand the code. This is not the right type of question for Stack Overflow, it should never have been migrated here.